Why does Ubuntu LiveUSB installer ignore the boot drive selection?
I've noticed this for a really really long time, as far back as 6.06. Every time I keep thinking I'll try it again and the installer totally ignores the selection.
It makes me wonder what that selection is actually for if it's just going to ignore it and pick a different drive instead.
Basically: When you want to do a fresh install or if you're upgrading an existing one, but have multiple drives with multiple boot EFI partitions (e.g. one for Ubuntu and one for Windows). Why will it ignore your selection and randomly pick one of the available ones instead.
Usually, I've noticed, it'll pick the one that is my main one. However, sometimes I want to test out a new Ubuntu without messing up any of the existing OSes... and I explicitly want it to use the new one I've set up for it. And yet it ignores the selection. It doesn't matter if I select the drive (e.g. /dev/sdb) or the partition (e.g. /dev/sdb1 or /dev/sdb2 depending on where the EFI is).
It seems like no one appears to be talking about this issue, and maybe it's just me. Or maybe everyone has been doing the worst workaround like I've had to do and that's unplug all the other driver. It's awful. It makes it hard to trust the installer sometimes when it can't even do this explicit selection correctly.
Thoughts? Anyone know why it does this?

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Grub installs to wrong disk. Do add yourself to the "Does this affect me?" list on the bug.
There are workarounds/solutions in the bug comments. Another problem is that your host system probably will not boot without the external device (since needed grub files are on it). There is a different installer (subiquity) since Ubuntu 23.10 for the desktops that doesn't have this problem. There are other installers that may not have the problem either, but ubiqity certainly still does.

I’m voting to close this question because this just a rant masquerading as a question. Often the answer for "why doesn't  work the way I want" is just ... because no one has put in the effort to make it work that way.

@muru I don't mind if it gets closed. In all honesty it was a bit of a rant, but I was genuinely curious why it ignored it at a technical level. ubfan1 example is assuming I'm using external drives, but the drives aren't, they're all internal using the SATA plugs, which is why I've always wondered why the installer ignores it. I've always understood why external USB based drives get ignored, just not the internal ones.

@ubfan1 thanks for the link, I'll definitely follow that to see what happens. I have noticed that the same issue still exists on the noble installer because I went from 20.04 to 22.04 to 24.04 earlier. I'm currently on the 24.04 part and instantly saw that although I picked an internal drive, it's still updating it to the nvme drive.

In your case, it may be because you have the ESP on the NVMe drive in your fstab. It defaults to that. A new install will let you choose unless an older version with ubiquity installer. You can edit fstab to UUID of desired ESP. Then run a total reinstall of grub. That will also update UEFI boot entry.

You should not use more than 1 EFI partition. It is designed to be shared between all OSes on a computer.

If you have an ESP - efi system partition mounted in fstab, that will be the default that grub install uses.
If  an external drive you need to have ESP on external drive, if going to use external drive with another system or ever disconnect it.
Or if multiple drives you may want to use ESP on Ubuntu drive. Install & update normally use default ESP on first drive, whatever UEFI/BIOS has defined as first drive.
Check drives mounted & fstab. The lsblk will show UUID & compare to fstab's UUID mount of ESP.
lsblk -f
cat /etc/fstab
mount

If then changing UUID in fstab.
sudoedit /etc/fstab

If booted into your install you can totally update UEFI & grub. Assumes many defaults and only works if correct ESP & UEFI settings.
sudo grub-install

Otherwise you may need to chroot into install or use Boot-Repair and Boot-Repair's advance mode to choose an install and drive to install into.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/
Some examples of chroot, but may vary depending on your configuration.
UEFI chroot, must include ESP - efi system partition
Can I install in UEFI mode with the alternate installer?
chroot with UEFI, LVM, encryption on NVMe drive
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2349833&p=13602088#post13602088
